# jQuery не отлавливает клик по абсолютно спозиционированному элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Есть следующая структура:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Элемент с классом `.parent` спозиционирован абсолютно. А элемент с классом `.child` спозиционирован относительно. Я повесил событие `click` на `$('window')` и проверяю, что есть целью(`e.target`). Так вот, когда я кликаю по родительскому элементу, то в консоль выводится, что я кликнул по дочернему элементу `.child`. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте место `e.target` , вывести `this` , или `e.currentTarget` !

Answer (score 0):

в кого кликаешь - тот и таргет.

```js
$(window).click(e=> console.log(e.target));
```

```css
.parent{
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
.child{
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот ответ на сам вопрос, содержащийся в теле: почему так происходит?

Называется весь этот беспредел - `event bubbling`и `event capturing`, почитай [Статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело во [всплытии](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling). Используйте `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
$('window').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(event.target);
});
```